# I Can Not Select element created dynamically for clone after

Tags: jquery, html, dom

The problem is simple, I can not select a dynamically created element.

As I can not select, I can not clone with dotted borders.

My application image:

[I can not select element created dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REnp1.png)

Mi code HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="a">Hello <button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
 <li class="a">Stack <button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
 <li class="a">Overflow <button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
</ul>
```

Mi jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var wrapper = $("<div class='wrapper' /></div>");
  $(".a").wrap(wrapper);
});

$(document).on("click",".clone",function() { // FUNCTION CLONE <LI ELEMENT>

     //$($(this).parent().parent().html()).insertAfter($(this).parent().parent());//Wrong

      $($(this).parent().parent().html()).clone().insertAfter($(this).parent().parent());//Wrong

});
```

Mi CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
.clone{
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
}
ul{padding:1em;}
```

My code online (See to understand):

http://jsfiddle.net/3vcho8jt/

*Note: My english is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of: `div` is not a valid child of `ul`, therefore wrapping your LI into `div` is a no-no. Instead add your style classes to the LI elements.
Than simply use `.closest()` to get a button closest selector, and `.clone()` it. Than you can use `.after()` to do insertions:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  // DIV is not a valid UL child! Add .wrapper class to LI instead
  $("ul li.a").addClass('wrapper');

  $(document).on("click", ".clone", function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest('li'); // Get the closest .wrapper AKA: LI element
    var $clone = $li.clone(); // Create a clone
    $li.after($clone); // Yep
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

.clone {
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">Hello<button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
  <li class="a">Stack<button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
  <li class="a">Overflow<button class="clone">Clone</button></li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it helped me a lot.

I made a variant with wrap(). Perfect:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/zq1ay30j/6/)